# How to display the Computer icon in the desktop?

Tags: nautilus

I installed dconf editor and gconf editor. I can enable trash, network and home icon using dconf editor. However, I can't find computer icon. I have searched Google and many other forums, but I cna't find any results about computer icon details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dconf approach will not work as there is not computer entry but you can create a file in your Desktop. At a terminal type:

```
gedit $HOME/Desktop/Computer.desktop&
```

Copy and paste the text below in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=nautilus computer:///
Name=Computer
Icon=computer
```

Make the file executable by typing in the terminal:

```
chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/Computer.desktop
```

Reference:  `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1852458`